Unable to install Rasa in windows machine
I was trying to install Rasa, using the command pip install rasa in my windows 10 laptop.
I have Python version 3.11 installed.
But am getting the below errors:
Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line   
     353, in <module>    
          main()
    File "C:\python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335,   
    in main        
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What am I missing? Previously, i was trying to install chatterbot module and i was stuck with similar error as well.
Also, I tried with pip install chatterbot as well, but still got error.

Currently, Rasa officially supports Python 3.7 to 3.10. Python 3.11 is not yet fully supported.
First install python version between 3.7 and 3.10 , and then retry pip install rasa command
For additional details, please refer to this.
RASA docs
